# How to remove the "visited" state from a link when I scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visited

I have a one-page landing page that scrolls to various sections when I click buttons in the menu. ...

However, once I have clicked a button and then I manually scroll elsewhere on the page, the clicked button still has the "visited" pseudo-class. Its appearance doesn't match where I am on the page.

Even when I manually scroll back to the top of the page the button still has the visited pseudo-class.  I can't seem to override its appearance by giving it a regular class.

I would like to remove that "visited" state the moment I begin to scroll manually.  How can I do that?  Is it possible?

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
        $("#menu-front-page-menu li a")...(how?);
}
});
```

Comment: "We’re limiting the CSS properties that can be used to style visited links to color, background-color, border-*-color, and outline-color and the color parts of the fill and stroke properties". https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the `:visited` pseudo class, you should style both your links and links visited the same way (pretty easy using CSS) and manage the "visited" style manually with [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and its contrary.